# Do barcodes allows to uniquely identify production items?

Tags: barcode

I hope this is the right place to ask.  I'm trying to learn about barcodes, I did some research and I wonder if, I can **uniquely** identify production patches (not just products).

For example, is it possible, given 2 Aspirin boxes, to differentiate them via barcode. It's not enough for me to just detect them as Aspirin, I need to uniquely identify each box.

Can this be done via barcodes?

Comment: If you're talking about the UPC barcode that is used to identify a product for pricing, no. But there's nothing that stops a manufacturer from putting other barcodes on a product to identify a lot/batch number or even an individual serial number.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with EE

Comment: @DaveTweed Thanks, no I'm not interested in pricing info, but as I said unique info which allows me to identify the box / item, for example trace a bad box back to original factory (or something like that)

Comment: yes you can. the much data you want will depend of the number of bars you are wanting to use. also, you may want to search for qr codes, which allows more data to be written/read

Comment: Like Dave said, a UPC barcode will just tell you that Aspirin is Aspirin. What else is on these boxes? The answer to this question will change from product to product, really.

Comment: @Gregd'Eon I'm not making the barcodes, I'm just reading them via a barcode reader (it's for medication)

Comment: A bar code is just a machine-readable bunch of characters. What they mean is up to you, in general. Of course standards exist for things like UPC, but you're free to create your own standards for internal use.

Comment: @TheDude Right - but if the Aspirin box doesn't have a barcode on it that specifies the factory/date/etc, then which barcode are you going to read?

Comment: @Gregd'Eon Aspirin was just an example (bad one, maybe :().

Comment: @TheDude Well, feel free to replace "Aspirin" with "Widget that comes in a box with barcodes on it": whether or not you can trace it back to the factory depends on whether or not the factory has made it traceable (and whether or not you can decipher the fact that "A17356BOQ56" means "Shipped on April 5, 2006")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Barcode is nothing but a ln alphanumeric sequence in machine readable format. There are various formats of 1D Barcode, with specific encodings or purposes like UPC or ISBN, as well as 2D codes like QR or 3D codes.

Regardless of the type, they can be fairly arbitrary in the data they hold.  Yes, you can use one for arbitrary production batch tracking by printing the same Barcode on each item in a batch.

But if you're trying to use an already printed Barcode for anything else other than what it was printed for, it won't work. In your specific case, the only Barcode on a aspirin box will be the UPC for that manufacturer and product code.

Comment: Thanks, not exactly what I was hoping for, but it does clarify things for me now!

Comment: @Passerby correct me if I'm wrong, but barcodes are only 1 dimension, since it matter only the width of each bar. On the other hand, QR codes are 2D, since it matter each block's height and width

Comment: @PedroQuadros Both 1D and 2D codes are commonly referred to as "barcodes". Also, most (but not all) 1D codes use the width of the space between bars as well as the width of the bars.

Comment: @Tut sure it uses both width. But do u agree the width of the space between bars are directly related to the width of bars? It's all a question of reference. If u have an example of 2D barcodes I'd like to see it, please.

Comment: @PedroQuadros The width of the bars is sometimes related to the width of the spaces in that the total widths of the bars and spaces making up a barcode "character" is often a constant. For some barcodes they are not related at all as their widths contain data for separate "characters" ( interleaved 2-of-5 for example). Most barcodes you cannot decode by just knowing the bar- widths or the space-widths. Examples of 2D barcodes are QR, Data-Matrix and PDF417

Comment: @Tut As I'm not a native english speaker I did not know barcodes are used for QR likes. They are not truly bars, but I checked and u are right. About the blank space I think u did not got my point. I was just saying u can deduct their width from the black bars. As the reciprocity is true.

Comment: @PedroQuadros The point I am tring to make is that for most (almost all) barcodes, you cannot deduct the space-widths from the bar-widths. The information they contain is NOT redundant. (BTW, I design barcodes and readers professionally and have done so for about 20 years)